# Will HTML need to turn to machine code before display on screen

Tags: html

After client browser get html responded from apache server, will this html codes need to interpret (maybe compile, I don't if I can use word "compile" instead of "interpret") to machine code for futher display or Browser just need to display these html codes directy on screen?

Answer (score 0):

They usually call it `rendering`.

See WIKI [post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine).

> A web browser engine, (sometimes called layout engine or rendering
>   engine), is a software component that takes marked up content (such as
>   HTML, XML, image files, etc.) and formatting information (such as CSS,
>   XSL, etc.) and displays the formatted content on the screen. It
>   "paints" on the content area of a window, which is displayed on a
>   monitor or a printer.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear enough, but my main question is : "Will browser compile html down to machine code for processor to do futher process or it just display directly on screen the html code?"

Comment: This is web browser engine dependent. For example, a particular web browser engine may choose to use operating system precompiled library to handle part or all of the rendering process. But in your context, the answer is no.